# How to test validation with react-testing-library and react form hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-hook-form for validation in a React component. In my separate test file (react-testing-library + vitest), how can I effectively test the validation logic, if I don't render anything (e.g. any error messages, as it's shown in docs example) when validation fails? Are there any recommended approaches for testing it? Should I perhaps mock useForm in test file?

[input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvKqr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use aria-invalid attribute on the input (changes the value depending on corresponding formState.errors object property), but ran into the problem that syncronous testcases didn't work as expected (attribute value never changed). I guess that's 'cause state mutation it React is async. Don't know if thats the right solution, but async testcases and *waitFor()* solved my problem:

```
describe("Invalid names work as expected", async () => {
  const invalidNames = [
    "21username", // Starts with a number
    "us ername", // Contains a space
    "a".repeat(25), // Exceeds the maximum length of 23 characters
    "-username", // Starts with a special character
  ];

  for (const name of invalidNames) {
    it(`"${name}" is not valid`, async () => {
      render(<MockRegisterPage />);
      const usernameInput = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
        name: /username/i,
      });

      fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: name } });
      fireEvent.blur(usernameInput);

      expect(usernameInput).toHaveValue(name);

      await waitFor(() => expect(usernameInput).toBeInvalid());
    });
  }
});
```